# Add class to parent div of a button

Tags: jquery

I am struggling to add a class to the parent element of a button - I cant seem to work out the syntax to target just the parent of the `<a>` clicked - note I have many divs with the same markup, so i just want the parent `<div>` of the `<a>` clicked to have the class change...

Why does the below not work?

I want to add the class "singleBio_BGZIndexer" to the ".nectar-post-grid-item.single" `<div>`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".culturePageTeamBiosWrapper .nectar-post-grid .nectar-post-grid-item.single a.teamBioChevron").click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".nectar-post-grid-item.single").addClass("singleBio_BGZIndexer");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="culturePageTeamBiosWrapper">
  <div class="nectar-post-grid">
    <div class="nectar-post-grid-item single">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="teamBiosItemContentWrapper">
            <a href="#" class="teamBioChevron"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".culturePageTeamBiosWrapper .nectar-post-grid .nectar-post-grid-item.single a.teamBioChevron").click(function(){

event.preventDefault();

$(this).parents('.nectar-post-grid-item').addClass("singleBio_BGZIndexer")

});
```

```css
.single.nectar-post-grid-item { background: yellow; }
.singleBio_BGZIndexer { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="single nectar-post-grid-item animated-in" data-has-img="true">
  <div class="inner" style="overflow: visible;">
    <div class="nectar-post-grid-item-bg" style=""></div>
    <div class="bg-overlay singleBio_Expanded" style=" background-color: #fbef62;" data-opacity="0.3" data-hover-opacity="0.4"></div>
    <div class="content singleBio_Expanded">
      <a class="nectar-post-grid-link" href="#" aria-label="123"></a>
      <div class="item-main">
        <h3 class="post-heading"><a href="#"><span class="accordionToggleCross"><img src="cross-grey.svg" title="Read more" alt="Read more"></span><span>Title</span><span class="chevron"><img src="arrow.svg" alt="Read more" title="Read more"></span>
         
         </a></h3>
        <p id="foliotItemDescription"></p>
        <p class="location" id="foliotItemLocation"></p>
        <a href="#" class="projectsFeedItemChevron"><img src="arrow.svg" title="View project" alt="View project"></a>

        
      </div>
      <div class="teamBiosItemContentWrapper single">
        <a href="#" class="teamBioCloser fademeIN"><img src="cross-grey.svg" alt="Close" title="Close"></a>
        <h3 style="margin-right: 50px;">Title</h3>
        <h5>Role</h5>
        <div class="teamBio_blurbWrapper">
          <p class="fademeIN">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nisl malesuada interdum sagittis auctor eu vestibulum amet, ipsum lorem. Sit ultrices pharetra, a, sit. Nisl malesuada interdum sagittis auctor eu vestibulum amet. Nisl malesuada interdum
            sagittis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Malesuada interdum sagittis Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nisl malesuada interdum sagittis auctor eu vestibulum amet, ipsum lorem. Sit ultrices pharetra, a, sit. Nisl malesuada
            interdum sagittis.</p>


          <h6 class="fademeOUT">BIO</h6>
          <a href="#" class="teamBioChevron fademeOUT">CLICK ME</a>

        </div>
        <!-- end of TEAM BIO STUFF -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without the HTML there is no way to know if this has a proper Selector or target.

Comment: just added the markup

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".culturePageTeamBiosWrapper .nectar-post-grid .nectar-post-grid-item.single a.teamBioChevron").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".nectar-post-grid").addClass("singleBio_BGZIndexer");
  });
});
```

```css
.single.nectar-post-grid-item {
  background: yellow;
}

.singleBio_BGZIndexer {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="culturePageTeamBiosWrapper">
  <div class="nectar-post-grid">
    <div class="nectar-post-grid-item single">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="teamBiosItemContentWrapper">
            <a href="#" class="teamBioChevron">Click Me</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This seems to work just fine. You can use `.parent()` with entry to select the parent element.

**Update**

What you want is `.closest()` to target an element further up the hierarchy.

Resulting HTML is:

```
<div class="culturePageTeamBiosWrapper">
  <div class="nectar-post-grid singleBio_BGZIndexer">
    <div class="nectar-post-grid-item single">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="teamBiosItemContentWrapper">
            <a href="#" class="teamBioChevron">Click Me</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since a Child element has a Styling, you will not see the Red background, since the child is covering it.

Comment: thanks - but doesnt seem to work on my actual code - i've just added a more comprehensive markup example... can you have a look?

Comment: $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().addClass("singleBio_BGZIndexer"); works - needed to add it to the 5th level parent up the tree!

Answer (score 1):

> ... the `parent()` method traverses to the immediate parent ...
>
> -- https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Try `closest()` instead.

> ...the .closest() method searches through these elements and their ancestors ...
>
> -- https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest-selector

```
$(function() {
  $(".culturePageTeamBiosWrapper .nectar-post-grid .nectar-post-grid-item.single a.teamBioChevron").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".nectar-post-grid-item.single").addClass("singleBio_BGZIndexer");
  });
});
```

The structure of your examples do not match, and you have a css selector specificity issue as well. You will see the following snippet works using your original example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".culturePageTeamBiosWrapper .nectar-post-grid .nectar-post-grid-item.single a.teamBioChevron").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".nectar-post-grid-item.single").addClass("singleBio_BGZIndexer");
  });
});
```

```css
.single.nectar-post-grid-item {
  background: yellow;
}


/* the following selector is more specific, so it will take priority over the previous */

.single.nectar-post-grid-item.singleBio_BGZIndexer {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="culturePageTeamBiosWrapper">
  <div class="nectar-post-grid">
    <div class="nectar-post-grid-item single">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="teamBiosItemContentWrapper">
            <a href="#" class="teamBioChevron">click me</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For your second example, the following works:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".nectar-post-grid-item.single a.teamBioChevron").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".nectar-post-grid-item.single").addClass("singleBio_BGZIndexer");
  });
});
```

```css
.single.nectar-post-grid-item {
  background: yellow;
}

.single.nectar-post-grid-item.singleBio_BGZIndexer {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="single nectar-post-grid-item animated-in" data-has-img="true">
  <div class="inner" style="overflow: visible;">
    <div class="nectar-post-grid-item-bg" style=""></div>
    <div class="bg-overlay singleBio_Expanded" style=" background-color: #fbef62;" data-opacity="0.3" data-hover-opacity="0.4"></div>
    <div class="content singleBio_Expanded">
      <a class="nectar-post-grid-link" href="#" aria-label="123"></a>
      <div class="item-main">
        <h3 class="post-heading"><a href="#"><span class="accordionToggleCross"><img src="cross-grey.svg" title="Read more" alt="Read more"></span><span>Title</span><span class="chevron"><img src="arrow.svg" alt="Read more" title="Read more"></span>

          </a></h3>
        <p id="foliotItemDescription"></p>
        <p class="location" id="foliotItemLocation"></p>
        <a href="#" class="projectsFeedItemChevron"><img src="arrow.svg" title="View project" alt="View project"></a>


      </div>
      <div class="teamBiosItemContentWrapper single">
        <a href="#" class="teamBioCloser fademeIN"><img src="cross-grey.svg" alt="Close" title="Close"></a>
        <h3 style="margin-right: 50px;">Title</h3>
        <h5>Role</h5>
        <div class="teamBio_blurbWrapper">
          <p class="fademeIN">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nisl malesuada interdum sagittis auctor eu vestibulum amet, ipsum lorem. Sit ultrices pharetra, a, sit. Nisl malesuada interdum sagittis auctor eu vestibulum amet. Nisl malesuada interdum
            sagittis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Malesuada interdum sagittis Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nisl malesuada interdum sagittis auctor eu vestibulum amet, ipsum lorem. Sit ultrices pharetra, a, sit. Nisl malesuada
            interdum sagittis.</p>


          <h6 class="fademeOUT">BIO</h6>
          <a href="#" class="teamBioChevron fademeOUT">CLICK ME</a>

        </div>
        <!-- end of TEAM BIO STUFF -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmmm not working on my live version... not sure why! As I have loads of indentical divs with the same markup - is there a better way to target just the div I have clicked within it and isolate it from the others

Comment: just added a more comprehensive markup example... can you have a look?

Comment: $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().addClass("singleBio_BGZIndexer"); works - needed to add it to the 5th level parent up the tree!

Comment: See my updated answer.